# How to merge a branch with only part of a commit of a different branch

Tags: git, merge

I want to merge few code lines of a commit belonging to a different branch into a new commit of my `master`, i.e. using a  difftool apply only some changes of another commit.

I tried from `master` with

```
merge --no-commit --no-ff newJob
git reset .
```

but then I don't know how to choose only part of the changes.

This is because I'm writing my CV in latex and I want to create a different branch when I use a different template, a new layout, or when I want to customize it for a particular job. 
Then it happens that I update or correct details in the branch, let's say, `newJob` and I have to correct these details also into the `master`. Using a difftool would be really quick.

Answer (score 1):

A recorded merge says all changes that need to be applied have been; later merges of the two histories won't reexamine changes you discard in this merge.  It may not be what you want here.

To apply just a few changes from commit B, do e.g.

```
git diff-tree -p B file ... | git apply
git add -p .             # (this is the pick-my-diffs command you wanted)
git checkout file ...    # (optional, undo any changes not staged)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use git cherry-pick to achieve it。

```
git checkout branch-B
git cherry-pick commit-a2
```

it can merge the commit of branch-A to branch-B.

Comment: I think the question was about selecting a few lines of a commit, not selecting a specific commit out of several commits.